# How do check if the item selected in list item in SPD2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, web, list-view-web-part

I want to fire Click event on my other web part when I select the item in LV web part.

Comment: Is this in Sharepoint Designer ? or list view page

Comment: Yes Sharepoint Designer

Comment: you mention LV web Part it's list view

Comment: I am using Wiki page on this wiki page i add List View web part. I want fire Click event when user select the item in List view web part row

Comment: Also one thing I want to fire click event  in other web part 1st row result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery To execute script when the list item has been selected by doing the following

- Edit Page.
- Add Script Editor.

> ```
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     $(function () {
>
>         $(".ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr").click(function(){
>             alert("write the code here");
>         });       
>     });   
> </script>
> ```